# Using input type="number" with decimal angular data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, input

I've been working on a site using angular and have came across a problem filling in an input. I have a form which I pull info in from a factory to let the user update their default settings.

I use `input type="number"` like this:

```
<div class="div-table-row">
     <input type="number" min="0" data-ng-model="locDefaults.NoDaysDlvryInst" />
</div>
```

for integers. It works well and lets them use the up/down arrows like I want.

However when I try to use the similar logic with decimal numbers it won't pull in my angular data... I've found a couple things online, but nothing worked. Most recently, I tried the logic [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2SgJ/8/) uses.

It didn't work for me, but here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="div-table-row">
     <input type="number" step="0.01" data-ng-model="locDefaults.WarnNearCapacity" decimal-places />
</div>
```

custom angular directive:

```
myApp.directive('decimalPlaces',function(){
    return {
        link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
            ele.bind('keypress',function(e){
                var newVal=$(this).val()+(e.charCode!==0?String.fromCharCode(e.charCode):'');
                if($(this).val().search(/(.*)\.[0-9][0-9]/)===0 && newVal.length>$(this).val().length){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Has anyone run into this issue before? The data being pulled in will be a number like 0.950 it's used to represent a percentage so I really want to find a way to use the up/down arrow control to change the number.

Comment: Documentation is great: [step](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-step)

Comment: Use `$formatter` on the ngModel in a directive

Comment: Your issue is the value is not trimmed to 2 decimal places when the model is assigned a value right?

Comment: I cannot even get the value to show up. I'm more concerned about that than format at the moment

Comment: It is showing up http://plnkr.co/edit/sa8TUP?p=preview Which browser?

Comment: @PSL not sure why it won't work with input type="number". However if I change it to type="text" it will load in no problem. It is stored in the db as datatype decimal and would really like the options for my users to use up down arrows.

Comment: In my plunker i shared in my previous comment i see it getting loaded though

Comment: @PSL I know. I see it too. Not sure what the problem is then. Thank you for the help!